# Invalid Scope: user_birthday iOS swift

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, parsefacebookutils

it was working fine 2 months ago (facebook took 2 months to review the app permissions) but now its showing me this error

Invalid Scope: user_birthday. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present.

Using the sdk through parse

Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.26.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.26.0)
Using Parse (1.15.2)
Using ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.11.1)
Using ParseLiveQuery (2.2.1)

Comment: did you check out the changelog? where is the relevant code?

Comment: What does the app dashboard say, does it show that permission as reviewed and approved?

Answer (score 4):

The message means that Facebook hasn't approved your app for use of the `user_birthday` permission.

Check the App Dashboard on Facebook to confirm that review status, and also make sure you're using the correct App ID in your iOS code.

While you're see that message `shown to developers` message in the login flow, other users will see the generic login prompt and won't be asked to grant the `user_birthday` permission, so your app will behave as though users are rejecting the permission.

Comment: And what if my `user_birthday` is approved and is green but i still get an error message?

Comment: Did the user whose access token you're using grant you the user_birthday permission? you can check by making a call to /me/permissions with the access token, or debugging it in the access token debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/